# Java: How do I check the if a char at the nth position of a string is a letter or if is a number?

Tags: java, string, char

Let's say I have this string: "abcd123fx".
Now, I want to make a method which checks (in order) if "a","b","c","d" etc is a number and if not, returns false. I don't know how to handle the n-th position of char and for each char, in order.

Answer (score 6):

You can check if a character is a letter of number with teh Character class.

```
String text = ...
char ch = texct.charAt(nth);
if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
    // is a letter
} else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
    // is a digit
}
```

Note: these method support characters in different blocks of the unicode. e.g. it will accept characters in Arabic or Korean.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation. You can use [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) function.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Character.isLetter(yourString.charAt(index)))
    // ... Letter

if (Character.isDigit(yourString.charAt(index)))
   // ... Number
```

Check [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/charintro.html)

Comment: This solution is way too C-like. Why don't you use Character's methods, as described in the page you linked?

Answer (score 2):

Well there are a few ways you could do this. The simplest would probably be something along the lines of:

```
Character.isDigit(someString.charAt(x))
or  a regex way would be someString.substring(x,x).matches("[0-9]")
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the nth character of a string you should use [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29), the you should use the Charachter's [isLetterOrDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit%28char%29).

Usually, when you face these problems, you should search the javadoc looking for suitable methods.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) on oracle.com for more information.

Specifically for this subject:

- [Characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), specifically the [`Character.isLetter(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) and [`Character.isDigit(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) methods
- [Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) and [Manipulating Characters in a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html), the simplest method is [`String.charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

**-** As you have said that you are a newbie, i won't make this complicated using `Regex`, but **will use inbuilt Java functionalities to answer this**.

**-** First use `subString()` method to get the "abcd" part of the String, then use `toCharArray()` method to break the `String` into `char` elements, then use `Character` class's `isDigit()` method to know whether its a digit or not.

**Eg:**

```
public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        String s = "abcd123fx";

        String str = s.substring(0,4);
        System.out.println(str);

        char[] cArr = str.toCharArray();

        for(char a :cArr){

            if(Character.isDigit(a)){

                System.out.println(a+" is a digit");
            }else{

                System.out.println(a+" is not a digit");
            }
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look into the ASCII table

Depending on this you can write a method:

```
private boolean isNumber(char a) {
    int i = a;
    if(i >= 48 && i <=57)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

// now you can look by a String

private void checkString() {
    String x = "abcd123fx ";

    for(char counter : x.toCharArray())
        System.out.println(isNumber(counter));
}
```

Comment: Why downvote this? I just wanted to show him, that he can also work with the ascii Table

Comment: who ever down-voted it doesn't understand the code so I gave you +1 to make it up for that. This is good code, btw.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    return str.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(isNumeric("abcd123fx"));
}
```

If you have a numeric string it will return true else false

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(checkNumber("123a44"));
}

public static boolean checkNumber(String s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```